# Агрегация и композиция

Tags: ооп, архитектура, проектирование

Здравствуйте!

Всегда считал, что агрегация — это синоним композиции, однако наткнулся на блог в интернете, где [приводятся отличия композиции от агрегации](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2012/12/vs-vs.html).

Мне это снесло крышу. Поясните, пожалуйста, плюсы/минусы и того и другого на небольших примерах. Как это влияет на расширяемость, тестируемость и т. д.

Comment: Там пояснено достаточно подробно. Вы лучше конкретные вопросы напишите.

Comment: да особо нечего спросить так сходу... хорошо бы если бы кто-нибудь разъяснил плюсы/минусы и того и другого на небольших примерах... как это влияет на расширяемость, тестируемость и т.д.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Существует несколько видов взаимодействия объектов, объединенных под общим понятием "Has-A Relationship" или "Part Of Relationship". Это отношение означает, что один объект является составной частью другого объекта.

Существует два подвида этого отношения: если один объект создает другой объект и время жизни "части" зависит от времени жизни целого, то это называется "композиция", если же один объект получает ссылку (указатель) на другой объект в процессе конструирования, то это уже агрегация.

Давайте рассмотрим пример из .NET Framework, чтобы увидеть, какие ограничения/последствия несут эти отношения: `StringWriter` + `StringBuilder`.

Класс `StringWriter` - это специализированная версия класса `TextWriter`, которые активно используются при сериализации и для получения текстового представления объектов.

Конкретно `StringWriter` создает строковое представление объекта или графа объектов и опирается на экземпляр `StringBuilder` в своей работе. Т.е. мы можем сказать, что 'StringWriter HAS A StringBuilder' или 'StringBuilder is part of StringWriter'. Теперь давайте посмотрим, как решить, должен ли `StringWriter` получать экземпляр `StringBuilder`-а извне или создавать его?

С одной стороны, нам, как клиенту класса `StringWriter` часто бывает все равно, что именно используется внутри этого класса для получения строкового представления. Это значит, что с точки зрения простоты использования лучше, чтобы `StringWriter` создавал экземпляр `StringBuilder`-а самостоятельно.

Но, с другой стороны, конкретный объект `StringWriter`-а может отвечать лишь за получения части строкового представления, а другая часть строки может вычисляться другим способом. С этой точки зрения, лучше, чтобы `StringWriter` принимал экземлпяр `StringBuilder`-а в конструкторе. Это же справедливо и для высоконагруженных систем, в которых разумно использование пула объектов.

Поскольку `StringWriter` - это библиотечный класс, который должен поддерживать оба сценария, то у него есть перегруженные версии конструктора: один из них создает `StringBuilder` внутри, а другой - принимает его снаружи.

Другими словами, выбор между композицией и агрегацией основан на соблюдении балланса между различными требованиями в дизайне:

**Композиция: объект A управляет временем жизни объекта B**

Плюсы:

- Композиция позволяет скрыть отношение использования объектов от глаз клиента.
- Делает API использования класса более простым и позволяет перейти от использования одного класса, к другому (например, `StringWriter` мог бы поменять реализацию и начать использовать другой тип, например `CustomStringBuilder`).

Минусы:

- Отношение достаточно жесткое, поскольку один объект должен уметь создавать другой: он должен знать конкретный тип и иметь доступ к функции создания. Композиция не позволяет использовать интерфейсы (без привлечения фабрик) и требует, чтобы класс имел доступ к конструктору другого класса: представьте, что конструктор `StringBuilder`-а является внутренним или же это интерфейс `IStringBuilder` и только клиенский код знает, какой экземпляр должен использоваться здесь и сейчас.

**Агрегация: объект А получает ссылку на объект B**

Плюсы:

- Более слабая связанность между объектом и его клиентом. Теперь мы можем использовать интерфейсы и одному объекту не нужно знать, как именно создавать другой объект.
- Большая гибкость. Вытекает из первого пункта

Минусы:

- Выставление наружу деталей реализации. Поскольку клиент класса должен предоставить зависимость в момент создания объекта (передать экземпляр `StringBuilder`-а в момент создания `StringWriter`-а, то сам факт этого отношения становится известен клиенту.
- Из первого пункта вытекает увеличение сложности в работе клиентов, а также большая "жесткость" решения в долгосрочной перспективе. Теперь автор класса `TextWriter` уже не может принять решение самостоятельно и перейти от `StringBuilder`-а к чему-то другому. Да, можно "добавить еще один уровень абстракции" и выделить интерфейс `IStringBuilder`, но разорвать это отношение совсем будет невозможно без поломки всех существующих клиентов.

В заключении: дизайн - это поиск компромисса между различными факторами. Композиция проще с точки зрения клиентов класса, но налагает определенные ограничения: "целое" должно уметь создавать "составную часть". Агрегация гибче, но налагает другие ограничения: теперь "целое" не скрывает о существовании "составной части", а значит и не сможет заменить ее на другую "составную часть" в будущем.

P.S. Если очень хочется использовать пример из реального мира, то для объяснения композиции и агрегации может подойти ... отвертка. Если отвертка цельная, т.е. ручка и насадка намертво связаны друг с другом, то мы имеем отношение **композиции**. Если же насадка съемная и может существовать без ручки или же использоваться с другой ручкой, то мы имеем отношение **агрегации**.

Comment: мда уж... пул объектов, фабрика интерфейсов... слабо у меня с теорией, спасибо

Comment: понял, что чтобы прочувствовать разницу, надо что-то очень большое писать, на мелких не удается порой решить даже простой выбор: тупо наследование или агрегация

Comment: Есть такое дело: в реальных задачах вылазит такое, что в обычных условиях в жизни на ум не прийдет.
Я бы рекомендовал даже личный проектом заняться плотно. Во многих моих проектах на гитхабе все это уже нужно. Хотя они и не очень большие: https://github.com/SergeyTeplyakov/

Comment: А почему когда Вы говорите о композиции, то каждый раз упоминаете о  совпадении времени жизни части и создающего её объекта, а когда о агрегации, то не говорите подобного? Просто Вы каждый раз делаете на это упор из чего может сложится впечатление что если при агрегации ссылка на часть будет так же по времени жизни совпадать с объектом, который хранит ссылку на эту часть, то это уже не будет агрегация. ведь все равно будет агрегация?

Comment: @OlmerDale тут вопрос не в совпадении времени жизни - а в управлении им.

Comment: @OlmerDale в случае композиции и агрегации - ограничение времени жизни - это ключевая характеристика. Если целое создает часть и не выпускает его наружу, то этим самым время жизни части ограничено целым. В случае же агрегации - часть и целое не связано столь плотно. В случае языков с GC в случае агрегации часть и целое могут умереть одновременно, но это скорее случайность, а не правило.