# Тестирование методов

Tags: c#, ооп, юнит-тесты

Подскажите как нужно писать модульные тесты для методов, которые вызывают другие методы?

Стоит ли такие методы отрефакторить в отдельные классы и потом в подсовывать подделки методу?

```
public class ClientProgramm
{        
    public void StartProgram()
    {

        // ... Some logic
        if (logic == 1)
        {
            Method1();
        }

        // ... Some logic
        else if (logic == 2)
        {
            Method2();
        }          
    }

    private void Method1()
    {
            ....
    }

    private void Method2()
    {
            ....
    }

    // many others private methods
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы описываете две проблемы.

При проектировании типов вы должны руководствоваться [принципом единой обязанности](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BF_%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8), который говорит вам о том, что класс должен выполнять одну задачу. Если вам кажется, что логика ваших приватных методов направлена на решение задач, отличных от класса в котором они используются, тогда – да, скорее всего в вашем классе присутствует скрытая абстракция. Каким отношением связать эту скрытую абстракцию с текущим классом решать вам, в зависимости от контекста ([агрегация/композиция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/596697/%D0%90%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F), наследование и т.д.). Отталкиваясь от отношений классов, такая же будет и стратегия тестирования.

Второй вопрос можно переиначить следующим образом: нужно ли тестировать приватные методы? И ответ – [да, нужно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/321346/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-private-%D0%B8-protected-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%8B). Но это будет косвенно, через тестирование основных и граничных условий в публичных методах.

Answer (score 1):

Тестирование должно зависеть не от того, кто кого вызывает, а от ТЗ на ваши методы.

Найдите ТЗ (или напишите его сами), и проверяйте в тестах, соответствуют ли они ТЗ.

(Для этого, возможно, понадобится провести рефакторинг и исключить жёсткие зависимости от нижележащих модулей.)

Comment: Есть ТЗ, есть тесты. Просто тест отправляется гулять дальше по вызову методов и не проходит. Вопрос как разорвать связь или как написать тест.

Comment: Не проходит — значит, у вас ошибка. Ну или ошибка в коде теста.