# Правильно ли я понял тему агрегации и композиции?

Tags: java

Композиция и агрегация представляют собой создание объект-ов(а) класса в общем классе.

В случаях использования композиции и агрегации, класс не «является» (предпочтительней наследование), а «является частью». Рука не является человеком, но является частью человека(пример композиции). Пистолет не является полицейским, но является частью полицейского(пример агрегации).

Композиция контролирует жизненный цикл своих составных частей, в агрегации они могут жить и отдельно. Разница композиции и агрегации в контроле жизненного цикла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разница между композицией и агрегацией в различных требованиях к дизайну класса. Вместе с тем ваше утверждение "Разница композиции и агрегации в контроле жизненного цикла." тоже верно. Есть отличный ответ на эту тему: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597085/217374

Comment: То есть агрегация это(про полицейского) - бери пистолет, форму, значок и иди работай? Когда мы тебя уволим, то отберем у тебя эти вещи. Мы снимем отпечатки с пистолета, возьмем твои другие "биологические" данные с формы и оценим поношенность всего этого(мы используем эти данные, если понадобится (͡° ͜ʖ ͡°) ). А потом решим, что с этим делать.

Мне еще интересна тех часть вопроса. Агрегацией можно называть только использование объекта извне(не создаем в классе, принимаем его из конструктора или метода)? Или это определяется этической частью(пример полицейского, но(!!!) с объектом ВНУТРИ)?

Comment: Не дописал(Ограничение в символах): Объект то внутри, но наш класс не имеет методов(конструктора) для получения объекта извне(ссылка).

Comment: Агрегация - это когда пистолет передан нашему полицескому извне (конструктор, сеттер). Композиция - это когда у полицеского есть, например, татуировка пистолета: она является частью этого полицейского и рассматривается только в составе этого конкретного полицейского. Надеюсь, я верно понял вопрос.

Comment: Добавил это: "Агрегация - это когда ссылка на объект класса передана извне (конструктор, сеттер). Объект дается  лишь на пользование. 
Композиция — объект принадлежит гл. классу и неотделим."

Все правильно?

Comment: Да, все правильно

Answer (score 3):

В целом все верно.
*Композиция* и *агрегация* являются частными случаями *ассоциации*.

- **Ассоциация** - это когда классы имеют ссылки друг на друга, так как им необходимо взаимодействовать между собой. Например, класс `Собака` и класс `Человек`. Оба являются независимыми, самодостаточными, но иногда они взаимодействуют между собой
- **Композиция** - это когда какой то класс является самодостаточным, а другие не могут независимо от него существовать. Например, класс `Рука` и класс `Человек`. Рука является частью Человека, но она не может существовать отдельно от Человека.
- **Агрегация** - аналогично композиции, но здесь уже класс является самодостаточным и он может быть использован в различных классах. Например, класс `Телевизор` и класс `Бабушка` и класс `Дедушка`. С Телевизором Бабушка и Дедушка могут выполнять различные действия, не обязательно что только один класс.

Более подробно и с uml диаграммами можете ознакомиться [по ссылке](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/guide/uml-unified-modeling-language/uml-aggregation-vs-composition/)