# Чем отличается dependency injection от композиции?

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection

Один из вопросов собеседования. В чем отличия?

Answer (score 2):

Dependency Injection - это один из способов реализации инверсии контроля (принцип используемый для уменьшения связанности кода). В этом случае зависимости передаются через конструктор (как правило) или через установку свойств (реже).

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461814/Зачем-нужен-dependency-injection-контейнер](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/461814/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-dependency-injection-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80)

Композиция - это частный случай ассоциации (это когда классы имеют ссылки друг на друга, так как им необходимо взаимодействовать между собой), при котором какой то класс является самодостаточным, а другие не могут независимо от него существовать.

[https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981263/Правильно-ли-я-понял-тему-агрегации-и-композиции](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/981263/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%8F%D0%BB-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%83-%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8)

То есть в общем случае, это термины из разных областей. Но если попытаться их сравнить, то можно заметить, что Dependency Injection построен на  агрегации (частный случай ассоциации) - аналогично композиции, но здесь уже класс является самодостаточным и он может быть использован в различных классах. Но самое главное отличие - это их назначение, при Dependency Injection управление жизненным циклом некоего компонента происходит извне этого компонента, а просто композиция нам этого не даёт - это лишь тип связи между объектами.