# Композиция и агрегация в ооп

Tags: ооп, любой-язык, solid

Подскажите пожалуйста,

1. в некоторых книгах по ООП и паттернам программирования пишут "Предпочитайте композицию наследованию".

Но при этом, когда читаю главу про SOLID, то получается какое-то непонимание.
Мне кажется, что Композиция противоречит принципу SOLID, а именно LSP. И нужно использовать агрегацию.

Подскажите в чем не прав, и что не так понимаю?

2. Правильно ли понимаю, что композиция и агрегация это и есть виды инъекции зависимостей? 
   Если да, тогда для чего также во всех книгах Композицию, агрегацию и наследование сравнивают вместе?

Объясните пожалуйста, никак не пойму.

Comment: Если можно, то с примерами пожалуйста)

Comment: Если композиция лучше наследования, почему тогда существует наследование? Что использовать, зависит от ситуации.

Comment: Хотя наверное лучше этот дубликат: [Агрегация и композиция](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/597085/186999)

Comment: _Мне кажется, что Композиция противоречит принципу SOLID, а именно LSP._ - почему ты так думаешь?

Comment: Подробное описание можно найти тут: [Наследование vs Композиция vs Агрегация](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.com/2012/12/vs-vs.html)

Comment: @Grundy потому что при композиции, экземпляр класса создается внутри методов определенного класса. А по принципу LSP, зависимости классов должны быть от абстракции.

Comment: @sadfsdfsdf, что-то не вижу где в LSP, указано что _зависимости классов должны быть от абстракции._? Ты уверен что понял в чем суть принципа подстановки Лисков?